# Two datasources in report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have two datatables loaded from my database and bound to my report:

```
objRpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dataTable1); 
objRpt.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(dataTable2);
```

When I try to put both datasources in, the data on the report multiplies. But when I put only one of them, everything is ok.

How can I configure my Crystal Report to correctly use two datasources?

Comment: Need more clarification. Why are there two data sources? How are they related if at all? Can you use a sub-report for one of the data sources?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're not linking the tables properly. Without proper links, the tables won't understand their relationship to each other and assume all the information is unrelated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiIl7Shir9k  Linking Multiple Tables Business Objects

Comment: 2 data source is not allow. even though 2 table is allow. also 2 different data source use Cartesian rule and give inaccurate data. can you explained what you want and what you achieve technically?